# (Swift HomeKit) Pairing home kit accessories, but "Setup Code" entry screen disappears before I have a chance to enter the code

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I'm writing a simple app to control my home kit lights. In my code, I try to add the selected device to my home, and it works somewhat. However, in my app, when It brings up the screen where I enter the "Setup Code", it disappears in 1-2 seconds and says "Home could not pair this accessory" before I get a chance to enter the Setup Code all the way.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit
import HomeKit

class HomeTestTableViewController: UITableViewController {


let homeManager = HMHomeManager()
var activeHome: HMHome?
var activeRoom: HMRoom?


var devices = [HMAccessory]()
var selectedAcc: HMAccessory?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return devices.count
    //devices[0].services.
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Configure the cell...
    let cellIdentifier = "HomeTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    cell.deviceName.text = devices[indexPath.row].name

    //setting button
    //let deviceSwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRect.zero) as UISwitch



    return cell
}

@IBAction func unwindToDeviceTable(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? AddDeviceViewController, let device = sourceViewController.addedAcc{

        homeManager.primaryHome?.addAccessory(device, completionHandler: { (error) in
            print("ACCESSORY SERVICES: \(device.services.count)")
        })

        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: devices.count, section: 0)
        devices.append(device)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .bottom)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedAcc = devices[indexPath.row]
    //print(selectedAcc?.services.count)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "viewDeviceDetail", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "viewDeviceDetail" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ShowDeviceViewController {
            destination.showSelectedDevice = selectedAcc 

        }
    }
}
}
```

In my "UnwindToDeviceTable" segue function, is when I try to save the accessory, from another view controller that's selecting the accessory. That parts working, but I don't know why the setup code screen disappears so quickly. Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: it seems likely that the device object is being released before you get a chance to respond to the dialog.

Comment: That's kinda what I'm thinking too, do you know how I would go about fixing that?

Comment: Either that, or I'm not adding the home correctly so it starts the setup and then fails